# TooTallNate's Websockets library WSS issue

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, java-websocket

Used TooTallNate's Websockets library to implement websocket server, it works perfect.
Now I need to implement Websockets secure. I created keystore as in  [example](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/SSLServerExample.java) and implemented WSS server.
Created keystore like this:

`keytool -genkey -validity 3650 -keystore "keystore.jks" -storepass "storepassword" -keypass "keypassword" -alias "default" -dname "CN=127.0.0.1, OU=MyOrgUnit, O=MyOrg, L=MyCity, S=MyRegion, C=MyCountry"`

(also tried to create keystore with `-keyalg RSA` parameter)

Now when I trying to connect the server with my JS client, successfull connect attempts are only 10% of all attempts. In rest 90% cases, Chrome console says `TIMEOUT` for WSS connection.
Tried to connect server using OpenSSL, WSS server provides certificate only one time after server starts.

From console with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` VM parameter:

> ```
> `Using SSLEngineImpl.
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
> Allow legacy hello messages: true
> Is initial handshake: true
> Is secure renegotiation: false
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
> [Raw read]: length = 5
> 0000: 16 03 01 00 94 .....
> [Raw read]: length = 148
> 0000: 01 00 00 90 03 03 3F 41 BA 59 AE 98 8B 40 F0 09 ......?A.Y...@..
> 0010: 7A 19 E8 A1 69 69 A2 74 40 14 32 72 D3 D7 2F D4 z...ii.t@.2r../.
> 0020: A3 6B 7C 3C 73 57 00 00 16 C0 2B C0 2F C0 0A C0 .k.<sW....+./...
> 0030: 09 C0 13 C0 14 00 33 00 39 00 2F 00 35 00 0A 01 ......3.9./.5...
> 0040: 00 00 51 FF 01 00 01 00 00 0A 00 08 00 06 00 17 ..Q.............
> 0050: 00 18 00 19 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 23 00 00 33 74 ...........#..3t
> 0060: 00 00 00 10 00 0B 00 09 08 68 74 74 70 2F 31 2E .........http/1.
> 0070: 31 00 05 00 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 0D 00 16 00 14 1...............
> 0080: 04 01 05 01 06 01 02 01 04 03 05 03 06 03 02 03 ................
> 0090: 04 02 02 02 ....
> WebsocketSelector35, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 148`
> ```

I seems to me it's some stupid misconfiguration from my side, but I can't figure out where it could be. Could you give me an advice how to solve it?

Comment: What's different in the 10% that are successful?

Comment: Wish I know that. it usually succeeds just after server restart

Comment: OK, but I suppose the log entries differ in some how from the ones that you posted. Correct?